# Merging recursively sorted linked list not running

Tags: python, list, sorting

I would like to merge 2 sorted linked lists in python by using the following code:

```
def merge_lists(h1, h2):
    if h1 is None:
        return h2
    if h2 is None:
        return h1

    if (h1.value < h2.value):
        h1.next = merge_lists(h1.next, h2)
        return h1
    else:
        h2.next = merge_lists(h2.next, h1)
        return h2


h1=[1,5,7]
h2=[2,4,6]
print (type(h1))

merge_lists(h1, h2)
```

I get the following error:

```
<class 'list'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-2f8d8dee291e> in <module>()
     17 print (type(h1))
     18 
---> 19 merge_lists(h1, h2)

<ipython-input-38-2f8d8dee291e> in merge_lists(h1, h2)
      5         return h1
      6 
----> 7     if (h1.value < h2.value):
      8         h1.next = merge_lists(h1.next, h2)
      9         return h1

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: *'list' object has no attribute 'value'* - this is a great reason

Comment: Thanks. So how can I change the code that it will work?

Comment: It looks like the main problem is that you're mistaking Python lists, which are actually arrays, for linked lists whose elements have members named `value` and `next`.  Python does not define anything like this, so if you want a linked list, you will need to create your own class that has those fields, then create your linked lists using that class.

Comment: I think your input requires linkedlist and not list

Comment: Can you define what do I have to pre-define as linked list class so the code will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is fine, but you are making (wrong) assumptions about how to express the list operations you want to perform.

```
def merge_lists(h1, h2):
    if h1 == []:
        return h2
    if h2 == []:
        return h1

    if (h1[0] < h2[0]):
        return h1[0:1] + merge_lists(h1[1:], h2)
    else:
        return h2[0:1] + merge_lists(h1, h2[1:])
```

Comment: This misses the intent.  No one would write an array-based merge sort like this because the array (list) copying makes it unacceptably expensive.  OP wants to merge linked lists, but was confused by the nonstandard Python term for an array.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHunter, Can you also add an option to define a linked list class with the field value so I'll can use the original code as well?

Comment: There are plenty of implementations of linked lists in Python on the web, probably even in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Python standard logic:

```
sorted(h1 + h2)
```